# Dynamically Allocated Array of a Class

Tags: c++

I've declared

```
private:
    Comment *commentArray;
    int arrSize;
```

in the header for the class in which it is used, called CommentManager.  These are initialized in the constructer, as follows:

```
arrSize = 1;
commentArray = new Comment[arrSize];
```

If I'm understanding this correctly, this should create an "array" of one Comment.  Then I set up the core function of this class:

```
void CommentManager::addComment(QString commText, int start, int end)
{
    Comment *saveArray;

    saveArray = new Comment[arrSize + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++)
        saveArray[i] = commentArray[i];

    delete[] commentArray;

    commentArray = saveArray;

    arrSize += 1;
```

This should enlarge the size of commentArray by one.  Then I want to add the comment data, which is done through a function declared in Comment:

Header:

```
private:
    QString comment;
    int startPosition;
    int endPosition;
```

Function:

```
void Comment::setComment(QString comm,int newStartPos, int newEndPos)
{
    comment = comm;
    startPosition = newStartPos;
    endPosition = newEndPos;
}
```

I call this function as follows:

```
    commentArray[arrSize].setComment(commText,start,end);
```

This results in a segfault: according to the debugger 'comment' doesn't exist.  As a result, I attempted to initialize the individual comment(s) in commentArray, but the compiler wouldn't compile that.  I'm not sure what's gone wrong here, and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are those things in headers wrapped by a `class { };`? Also, why aren't you using `std::vector`?

Comment: DO you know what the "Rule of three is"? If not don't do this you get it wrong. Use an object that already knows how to do memory management (std:vector or QVector). Also don't use English when code is better. Above you describe what is in the constructor (but you don't show the constructor????????? Just show the constructor it is more precise and we can see if you made any mistakes in defining it. What other constructors have you defined (why not just plunk the class down?????)

Comment: Vectors and maps (might it be Qt or std) and so on are cool devices, I use them all the time, but don't underestimate the raw power of a pointer lookup in an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 commentArray[arrSize].setComment(commText,start,end);
```

arrsize is one step too much.

An array with say size 10 is indexed from 0 to 9, using 10 will be out of bound.

Answer (score 3):

```
commentArray[arrSize].setComment(commText,start,end);
```

is always going to refer to an element that doesn't exist because you're pointing to one past the number of elements in the array. The statement should be

```
commentArray[arrSize-1].setComment(commText,start,end);
```

Also, instead of manually managing an array of objects, you should probably use a container class. If you can use boost, take a look at `boost::ptr_vector`. If not, consider using one of the following:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Comment> > commentArray;
```

or

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Comment> > commentArray;
```